# Find the mass of surface S using surface integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

S is the part of the plane x+2y+3z=6 in the first octant; the density at a point P on S is directly proportional to the square of the distance between P and the yz plane.

My attempt so far: 
the distance between P and the yz plane is x, so density=kx^2

f(g(y,z),y,z) where g(y,z)=6-2y-3z.

partial derivative gy=-2

partial derivative gz=-3

z limits: 0 to 6

y limits: 0 to 1

and then I'm about to plug it in to the surface integral equation.

But I dont think I'm doing this right...

Comment: Your limits on $y$ and $z$ should parametrize a triangle in the $yz$-plane, not a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Equation of plane 
$$ z = 2 - \frac x3 -\frac{2y}3$$
$y$ can range from $0$ to $3-\frac x2$ (solve for $y$ where $z=0$)

$x$ ranges from $0$ to $6$

So $$  M = k\int_0^6\int_0^{3-\frac x2}x^2 dy\; dx $$

You could also do

$x$ ranges from $0$ to $6-2y$

$y$ ranges from $0$ to $3$

So $$  M = k\int_0^3\int_0^{6-2y}x^2 dx\; dy $$

you should get the same answer in either case ( I think it works out to $M=54k$)